# is package.json file used by node?

Tags: node.js

Is package.json file used by node when the application starts or is it used only by the npm for installing dependencies?

What I really need to know is this: when I start the app using

## node myapp

Is the package.json file read or ignored?

Comment: link your code. do you read from it?

Comment: In my code I don't read my own package.json. Ok, the underlying question is: if I have dependency in package.json like "mongodb": "~1.4.0", but I actually have only mongodb 1.3.3 installed in node_modules, will my app still start since node does not really read package.json?

Answer (score 6):

`package.json` is actually used by node itself. Here is the code: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L101 Basically, when you `require` a directory, it checks if the directory has `package.json` and if does uses file from it's `main` property.

otherwise `package.json` is used only in `npm`, but nothings stops you from reading it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it reads package.json ! You can define your application starting point (file) that will be called when you type node "appName".

To define that and other parameters (dependencies..etc) type : npm init and follow the console wizard.

You can check this guide : http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/

Comment: I know about npm init. I was not sure if node reads it on startup.